# How to swipe a View controller over the top of another view controller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8.2

I have a table view controller and another view controller. Now my requirement is that i need to swipe the table view controller half over the another view controller when i swipe the view controller. The image i can show is like this:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this by using the Swipegesture . If possible how can i do this in Swift3?

Comment: Yes pull out menu or a side menu..

Comment: @Rob n your code it is moving from top to bottom how about left to right?

Comment: Before you start the animation, rather than adjusting the "x" coordinate of the "to" view to something offscreen, instead adjust the "y" coordinate off to the right.

Comment: @Rob to view can u please tell the code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there are libraries out there to do this for you, if you are going to do this yourself, the basic idea is that you can create a "swipe from edge" gesture recognizer to initiate a custom presentation of a view controller (that has your menu on it). It consists of:

- a custom transitioning delegate (conforming to `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol) that specifies the animation controller and interaction controller (both described below) to be used during the presentation of the next scene;
- an animation controller (conforming to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`) that dictates the animation of the scene from the right edge;
- an interaction controller (a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`) that you can use to optionally drive the transition via a gesture;
- a presentation controller (a `UIPresentationController` subclass) that dictates whether the presented view will be removed or not (in this case you do not want it removed), as well as any other chrome to be animated alongside the animated presentation of the new scene (e.g. you often dim or blur the presenting view); and
- gesture recognizers to drive the interaction controller.

For more information, see WWDC videos [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/) and [A Look Inside Presentation Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/228/).

See https://github.com/robertmryan/SwiftCustomTransitions/tree/rightside for a Swift 3 example that renders the following UX:

[image]

This is all admittedly complicated enough that you may well want to consider third party libraries for presenting slide-in menus. But if you wanted to "roll your own", these are the basic pieces involved.

Comment: how to bring the blue color view from left side?? It would be so kind of you if u tell this... :)

Comment: In your edge swipe gesture, you'd need to change the `edges` to `.left`. You'd also have to flip the signs for the `percent` (where you're looking for positive `x` changes, not negative ones) in the gesture handler. You'd also want to change the animation, perhaps called `PullRightAnimationController`, so that the `offToRight` frame is `offToLeft` instead (subtracting `x` by the width of the presented view rather than adding the width of the presenting view). Please give it a good faith attempt, and I can help if you have problems. But give it a go yourself, first.

Comment: i shall truly try and get back to you once it is a success or a failed attempt :)

Comment: i successfully got it. Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is first create and hide a `UIView` that lets you select those `UIViewController` on the right side of the screen and animate it to show when the user swipes.

Then you implement this method that returns `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, a class that you want to implement for custom transitioning.

`- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)
                   navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
        animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                     fromViewController:(UIViewController*)fromVC
                       toViewController:(UIViewController*)toVC`

This could be a good tutorial for custom transitioning.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Comment: Yep. By the way, the `animationControllerForOperation` shown here is for customizing navigation controller animations. He’d probably instead specify a `transitioningDelegate` for a custom presentation instead. But both techniques fall under the rubric of “custom transitions”.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). It gives you the behavior you are looking for in just a few lines of code. You can present an `SWRevealViewController` that will hold your *top* and *bottom* `UIViewController` and present that as your scene.

```
// Your Front View Controller
let frontStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FrontStoryboard", bundle: .main)
let frontVC = frontStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

// Your Rear View Controller
let rearStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "RearStoryboard", bundle: .main)
let rearVC = rearStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

// Create Reveal View Controller From Both
if let revealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearVC, frontViewController: frontVC) {
    present(revealVC, animated: true) {

    }
}
```

Using `SWRevealViewController` you can set the `UIViewController` that you are trying to do the sliding in as the `frontViewController` and you can present the `rearViewController` simply using a single line of code.

```
// When you import SWRevealViewController every UIViewController
// has a method revealViewController() that returns the revealViewController
// that you can tell to toggle it's reveal state using the below
self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
```

---

**EDIT**

I believe you are trying to build a sliding navigation menu. Here is a link to a [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path) tutorial where he is creating exactly the navigation you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: does it works on the view controllers which i need to present from inner menu view controllers?

Comment: Shall u please post a github project?

Comment: And i need to present the TableView on the top of every controller by swiping as shown in image

Comment: There is a link to the `SWRevealViewController` GitHub in my answer. What do you mean inner menu?

Comment: Yes SWRevealViewController has simple methods you can call that will replace the view controller that is shown with another like the manner you suggest with the table view selection.

Comment: inner menu means side menu. So flow goes like this -> Side menu click -> opens a view controller -> a button in the view controller -> clicks and presents a view controller -> in that view controller if i swipe it should show the menu controller.

Comment: @ChelseaShawra I edited my answer to include a link to a Ray Wenderlich tutorial where he shows you how to build that kind of navigation without `SWRevealViewController`. But `SWRevealViewController` would still be the easiest route to take.

Comment: But it is in objective c though.. I am new to iOS and i only know swift :)

Comment: Did you look at the SWRevealViewController examples on their GitHub? I really think you just need to look those over. It is stupid simple to use and it is in swift.

Comment: I cant see the swift samples. please do post the link :)

Comment: It is on their Github like I said. Here is a link to an AppCoda tutorial teaching you how to build what you need. Soak this up then go make it happen. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/