# Swift - Make UIViewController visible while adding new ViewController animated from TOP (via self.present)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add a view controller from top for that I have created a custom animation which works correctly. However, the background color of the view controller which is being added is setting to black, where as I just want it to be transparent so that the view controller below can be visible.

Here is the code to add custom animation:

```
let vc = Global.sharedInstance.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnimationViewControllerID") as! AnimationViewController
            vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        vc.personName = name
        let begin = CGRect(x: 0, y: -vc.view.frame.height, width: vc.view.frame.width, height: vc.view.frame.height)
        let end = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vc.view.frame.width, height: vc.view.frame.width)
        self.present(vc, animated: false) { () -> Void in
            vc.view.frame = begin
            vc.view.alpha = 0.5
            vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { () -> Void in
                vc.view.frame = end
            },
                           completion: nil)
        }
```

I tried setting the view controller's background color to clear but still, it's not making the background transparent.

Comment: This technique (presenting with no animation, and then animating after the presentation is done) is limited (you can't make it interactive; the appearance method `viewDidAppear` is called at the wrong time; etc.). What you want is custom transitions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213998/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/45764323/1271826 for examples of custom transitions via `present`.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the information Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the **presentation style** of the presented view controller to accordingly.

Set it to `overFullScreen` if you want it to display over the current window and to `overCurrentContext` if you just want to set it above the view controller's context.

Also, you should set `definesPresentationContext` to `true`.

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
vc.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Comment: It is correct , but  .overCurrentContext also work here doesn't it ?

Comment: @MikeAlter In some cases, yes. Edited my answer.